# Querying with MongoDB issue

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, search, nosql

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to query a collection that has this structure:

```
{
     origin : { lat : #, lng : #},
     destination : { lat : #, lng #}
}
```

with this query:

```
{
     origin : { lat : { $gte: in.lat-1, $lte : in.lat+1},
               lng : { $gte: in.lng-1, $lte : in.lng+1}
                },
      destination : { lat : { $gte: out.lat-1, $lte : out.lat+ 1},
                lng : { $gte: out.lng-1, $lte : out.lng +1}}
}
```

Essentially I am trying to find documents whose coordinates are in some range (here 1) of my in/out lats/lngs. But when I pass this query it does not match documents that I know it should. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it worked, but I split the origin and destination into its two child components (lat and lng) and queried on those - that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To request on a subdocument you have to do `origin.lat { $gte ...}`

```
db.collection.find({
  "origin.lat": {
    "$gte": 7,
    "$lte": 10
  },
  "origin.lng": {
    "$gte": 7,
    "$lte": 10
  },
  "destination.lat": {
    "$gte": 7,
    "$lte": 10
  },
  "destination.lng": {
    "$gte": 7,
    "$lte": 10
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HMTxZk5SqtR)